# How to put link to my attachments from another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## view/homework.html.erb

```
 <span class="content">
 <%= homework.content %></span>
 <span class="timestamp">
 #this link I want to put it to home page
 <%=link_to "attachment", homework.attachment_url if homework.attachment?%> 
 Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(homework.created_at) %> ago.
```

## view/static_pages/home.html.erb

```
   <span class="user">
      <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
   </span>
   <span class="content">
       <%= feed_item.content %>
   </span> 
   <span class="timestamp">
        <--Here I want put a link "attachment" from view/homework.html.erb -->
        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(homework.created_at) %> ago.
   </span>
```

## controllers/static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
      if signed_in?
        @homework = current_user.homeworks.build 
        @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
      end
    end
```

## controllers/homeworks_controller.rb

```
   before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
   before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

   def create
     @homework = current_user.homeworks.build(homework_params)
     if @homework.save
         flash[:success] = "Homework created!"
         redirect_to root_url
     else
         @feed_items = []
     render 'static_pages/home'
     end
   end
   def destroy
     @homework.destroy
     redirect_to root_url
   end

   def index
     @homeworks=Homework.all
   end

   private

   def homework_params
     params.require(:homework).permit(:content,:attachment)
   end
   def correct_user
   @homework = current_user.homeworks.find_by(id: params[:id])
   redirect_to root_url if @homework.nil?
    end
   end
```

How to define that method in controller ?
I just run migration AddAttachmentToHomeworks that all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing as little as you give from your application I suspect that a user has several homework items associated. So what you could do is either

```
<%=link_to "attachment", feed_item.user.homeworks.last.attachment_url if !feed_item.user.homeworks.last.nil? && feed_item.user.homeworks.last.attachment?%>
```

or you iterate over all homeworks and link to each attachment in a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
<--Here I want put a link "attachment" from view/homework.html.erb -->
```

You're thinking about it in the wrong way

Rails is built on the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), meaning every `view` is autonomous - meaning it doesn't hold any data of its own; it has to inherit the data from `controllers`

---

**Controller**

Your question of including an `attachment` from another view, starts in your controller.

When you render `view/static_pages/home.html.erb`, you're actually rendering the `home` action in the `static_pages` controller

This means when you render the `homework` attachment in your other view, you need to call the same data in the `home` controller action, like so:

```
#app/controllers/static_pages.rb
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
       homework = Homework.find "4"
    end
end
```